# How to model HTML navigation?

Tags: android, cordova, uml

I am using PhoneGap to develop and this is my Final Year Project which I need to document my implementation plan. Mostly people will use UML diagram for their projects but mine is using HTML pages and a table to navigate through the applications. I didn't use any class and object and I find it seems not logical to use UML diagram like class diagram, state diagram etc… Come across someone suggest IFML which I couldn't find any official published book (need proper reference for project) and there is little sites that mention about it.

My application user start application -> menu -> Mode 1 and mode2 — choose mode1 -> show mode1 levels — click level1 -> `pageA` access database and display differently using `pageA` as -> show rows of datas — after finish, return back to menu.

All these I navigate using HTML pages and I already use flowchart.

How should I model my application flow if mine is mostly use HTML pages? I don't have any classes for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several modeling languages tailored to modeling navigation flows between web pages. One of the most popular ones is [WebML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebML) (original [link in wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418040925/http://webml.org/webml/page1.do)) but there are several others around, just search for "navigation models"

Answer (score 0):

There is a website called [codiqa](http://codiqa.com/). 
This site will allow you to model your app quite quickly to get a general flow of how you want the phone app to work. You can even export the html after you have finished the design.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I am not looking for modeling the actual interface.

Answer (score 0):

WebML is going to become a standard in OMG, under the name of IFML (Interaction Flow Modeling Languages). You can find more at:
  [www.ifml.org](http://www.ifml.org)
and:
  http://www.modeldrivenstar.org/search?q=ifml

WebML / IFML is accompanied by a modeling tool called WebRatio ([www.webratio.com](http://www.webratio.com)) that also provides binding to BPMN models, full code generation, model-based debugging, documentation generation, and several other MDE-based features.

[Disclaimer: I'm with Politecnico di Milano and WebRatio, and among the inventors of WebML/IFML]